# modx revo вывод последних статей

Tags: javascript, html, cms, modx

основные новости на странице я вывожу вот так

```
[[!getPage?
                    &elementClass=`modSnippet`
                    &element=`getResources`
                    &showHidden=`1`
                    &tpl=`newsTpl`
                    &limit=`5`
                    &includeContent=`1`
                    &includeTVs=`1`
                    &processTVs=`1`
                    &tvPrefix=``
                    &parents=`[[*id]]`
                    &hideContainers=`1`
                    ]]
```

вывод последних новостей на этой же странице \я вывожу вот так

```
[[!getResources?
                    &showHidden=`1`
                    &tpl=`newsTpl`
                    &limit=`5`
                    &includeContent=`1`
                    &includeTVs=`1`
                    &processTVs=`1`
                    &tvPrefix=``
                    &parents=`29`
                    &hideContainers=`1`
                    &sortby=`{"publishedon":"ASC","createdon":"DESC"}`
                    ]]
```

если вместо descResourseTpl подставить newsTpl то работает, а так нет

Comment: а у вас создан чанк descResourseTpl с шаблоном вывода?

Comment: да, сделан, но через него не хочет выводить